# Android Handler is not updating automatically, rather it update when i touch the screen?

Tags: android, graph, bluetooth, android-handler

I am making graph of the data coming from Arduino via bluetooth. I am implementing live graph using GraphView Library. For the dynamic graph purpose I am using Handler. The problem is Handler is not automatically updating Graph. Graph is updated only when i touch the screen and then it become still. 
Here is the handler where graph is drawn.

Note that these two fuctions are in two different classes.

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what){
        case Bluetooth.SUCCESS_CONNECT:
            Bluetooth.connectedThread = new Bluetooth.ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected!", 0).show();
            String s = "successfully connected";
            Bluetooth.connectedThread.start();
            break;
        case Bluetooth.MESSAGE_READ:

            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, 5);                 // create string from bytes array

            //Log.d("strIncom", strIncom);
            if (strIncom.indexOf('.')==2 && strIncom.indexOf('s')==0){
                strIncom = strIncom.replace("s", "");
                if (isFloatNumber(strIncom)){

                    Series.appendData(new GraphViewData(graph2LastXValue,Double.parseDouble(strIncom)),AutoScrollX);
                    //GraphView.updateViewLayout(graphView, null);

                    //X-axis control
                    if (graph2LastXValue >= Xview && Lock == true){
                        Series.resetData(new GraphViewData[] {});
                        graph2LastXValue = 0;
                    }else graph2LastXValue += 0.1;

                    if(Lock == true)
                        graphView.setViewPort(0, Xview);
                    else
                        graphView.setViewPort(graph2LastXValue-Xview, Xview);

                    //refresh
                    GraphView.removeView(graphView);
                    GraphView.addView(graphView);

                }

            }

            break;

        }
    }
```

This is the function where data is being send to handler.

```
public void run() {

        byte[] buffer;  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                try {
                    sleep(30);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                buffer = new byte[1024];
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```